# Non-Linear Non-homogenious ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation $$x''+sin(x)=f(t),$$
1-I know the solution of the homogeneous system $x_h(t)$, is it possible to use it to find the general solution of the non-homogeneous system? I am looking for a solution in the following form $$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t \xi(t-t') f(t') dt' $$ but i don't know how to find $\xi (t-t')$.

2-Is it possible to find x(t) in terms of fourier series?

3- What other approximation methods can be used to solve this system? f(t) is a fluctuation force sampled from Gaussian distribution with zero mean and $\sigma=1$

Comment: The ODE for the pendulum is non-linear. The separate consideration of the homogeneous equation is meaningless. For the same reason a convolution formula / integral kernel formula for the general solution does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogenous equation is the equation of the mathematical pendulum with general solution the Jacobi amplitude

$$x(t)= 2 \text{am}(\frac{\omega}{2} (t-t_0) | i \frac{2}{\omega}) , \quad \text{math notation}$$

$$x(t)= 2 \text{am}(\frac{\omega}{2} (t-t_0), - \frac{4}{\omega^2}) , \quad \text{technical notation}$$

Verification by $$\sin(2 \text {am}) = 2 \text{sn} * \text{cn}, \text{am}'=\text{dn} $$

The amplitude is either oscillating for$\omega <2$ or rotating for
$\omega>2.$

Between both the solitary single loop for $\omega=2$,  $\text{am}(t,1)$

$$ x(t)= 4 \ \tan^{-1}(e^{t-t_0})$$

The homogenous equation is solved by the energy method, multiplication by $x'=\frac{dx}{dt}$, solving for $dt$ yielding by simple integration the inverse function as an elliptic integral $F$

$$t-t_0 = \ \text{F}(x,k).$$

By nonlinearity and our knowlegde about the highly sophisticated methods to solve the sine-Gordon PDE, to find the perturbation solutions of the mathematical pendulum simply by a linear additive method of impulses $f(t)dt$  seems to be  improbable or impossible.

Comment: Thank you so much, Excuse me, I have an additional question, could you please tell me what methods can be used to solve such differential equation?